# What is this double-drain piece called?

Tags: plumbing, drain, plumbing-fixture

My basement sink is a two-tub sink with each basin's drains as close to each other as they can be. Below is a picture of the actual drain piece beneath the sink - it is an integrated two-in-one drain, as you can see. Obviously it needs replacing, but I can't figure out what to Google to get this same piece. Any insight?

I have a more modern kit that just connects two separate drains, but the drain pipe exit to the wall is fairly high relative to the sink drains and I'm pretty sure adding any extra stuff is going to put me too low.

[image]

Comment: it's not obvious that it needs replacing.  find the leak.

Comment: It's going to be tough... the proximity of the stack and its inlet will make this a rough job with a p-trap; not much room to get creative there... And that's not even addressing the weird strainer assembly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those were used on dual utility sinks, aka laundry sinks that would be in the basement or garage, often made of concrete. In a lot of cases those were proprietary fittings for the maker of the sink, often sold by people like Sears or Montgomery Ward back in the 30s to 50s maybe. Most of the time when I have come across them, I just replace the sink. Those old concrete ones would crack and leak, as it appears your has.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to say that this was a purpose-built/proprietary drain assembly that was designed for and supplied with your special sink.

I have never seen one like that, and I have seen many many sink drains, p.o. plugs, pop-up assemblies, strainers, etc.

There are a lot of specialty plumbing parts available though. Like this one that I found when I Googled "double basket strainer":

[image]

Comment: there's a lot of things that are legal to sell that are not legal to use.

Comment: @Jasen, not in California... lol

Answer (score 0):

maybe it 2 P traps into a wye that connects to that stack, that will avoid the height of the under-sink tee.

Comment: Hmm you mean 2 P-traps that wye together before exiting? Interesting, I hadn't thought of putting the wye downstream of the p-traps. Might work. I'll try to figure out the measurements.